# Oracle: how to avoid "java session state cleared" error when loading a java class?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

Whenever I load a java class, I will get this error on my open sessions when I call a member of the class.  Is it possible to avoid this?

```
ORA-29549: class MH.Tbs has changed, Java session state cleared
ORA-06512: at "MH.TBS", line 2
ORA-06512: at line 4
29549. 00000 -  "class %s.%s has changed, Java session state cleared"
*Cause:    A class in use by the current session was redefined or dropped,
           invalidating the current Java session state and requiring that
           it be cleared.
*Action:   No action required.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not avoid this, but there are workarounds.

When you change (loadjava, dropjava etc for example) the classes used by java stored procedures, this happens. Recalling might work; ending your session, creating a new one and recalling will definitely work. This is like the pl/sql packages getting invalidated when related(dependent) objects are modified.

by the way, you might like to check this also:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=856644

Comment: what does "recalling" mean? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I used a java class being called by a function pl / sql oracle . I discovered that the cause was the System.println that existed in the java class. I removed them and it worked.**